# windows cmd command replacement for awk

Tags: windows-7

I have a large ascii file with 5 columns. I need to get rid of two of the existing columns and output in a new file. What command do I use in cmd windows environment to do this (I used to run awk or VI evitor in unix for this)? Thanks

Comment: I'm not as familiar with this command, but here is a related article I found: http://windows-powershell-scripts.blogspot.com/2009/06/awk-equivalent-in-windows-powershell.html

Comment: I've never heard of anything half as useful in windows, but there are ports... http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm